# Check for many empty parameters?

Tags: swift

I have the code to check for one empty parameter:

```
if let isEmpty = name?.isEmpty where isEmpty == false {
```

but I need to implement code to check if many are false? eg quantity and price as well as name... How would I got about this using this code?

```
if let isEmpty = name?.isEmpty where isEmpty == false {
    if let isEmpty = total?.isEmpty where isEmpty == false {
        if let isEmpty = price?.isEmpty where isEmpty == false {
           if let isEmpty = quantity?.isEmpty where isEmpty == false {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I put a list of them it doesn't work when I do a try catch loop at the end of the loop.

```
@IBAction func saveItems(sender: AnyObject) {
    let name = txtName.text
    let total = txtTotal.text
    let price = txtPrice.text
    let quantity = stepperValue.text

    if let isEmpty = name?.isEmpty || 
          isEmpty = price?.isEmpty || 
          isEmpty = total?.isEmpty || 
          isEmpty = quantity?.isEmpty where isEmpty == false {

    }

    // Create Entity
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

    // Initialize Record
    let record = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

    // Populate Record
    record.setValue(txtName, forKey: "name")
    record.setValue(txtTotal, forKey: "total")
    record.setValue(txtPrice, forKey: "price")
    record.setValue(stepperValue, forKey: "quantity")
    record.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "date")

    do {
        // Save Record
        try record.managedObjectContext?.save()

        // Dismiss View Controller
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    } 
    catch {
        let saveError = error as NSError
        print("\(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")

        // Show Alert View
        showAlertWithTitle(title: "Warning", message: "Your message could not be saved", cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    }

} 
else {
    // Show Alert View
    showAlertWithTitle("Warning", message: "Your to-do needs a name.", cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do?  What are you doing within the body of the inner most `if`?  Is there anything going on inside the bodies of the other  `if` besides the next layer of nesting?

Comment: I am trying to implement this code inside of a save button.. they all need to be saved to core data but i suppose theres not anything going on no?

Comment: Could just one parameter be = to false?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is a big (but single, without nesting), complicated `if` statement:

```
if let name = name, total = total, price = price, quantity = quantity
    where !name.isEmpty && !total.isEmpty && !price.isEmpty && !quantity.isEmpty {

    // use name, total, price, quantity

}
```

---

Another, arguably better solution is to unwrap them one at a time, step-by-step, with a `guard` statement per variable.

```
guard let name = name where !name.isEmpty else {
    // name is nil or empty
    return
}

guard let total = total where !total.isEmpty else {
    // total is nil or empty
    return
}

guard let price = price where !price.isEmpty else {
    // price is nil or empty
    return
}

guard let quantity = quantity where !quantity.isEmpty else {
    // quantity is nil or empty
    return
}

// use name, total, price, and quantity, all are non-nil, non-empty
```

---

Of course, depending on what you do in the case of them being nil or empty versus not, the first solution might be better written with a `guard`:

```
guard let name = name, total = total, price = price, quantity = quantity
    where !name.isEmpty && !total.isEmpty && !price.isEmpty && !quantity.isEmpty else {

    // something was nil or empty
    return

}

// use name, total, price, quantity
```

---

If I were writing this code, assuming that being `nil` or empty represents a state in which the data cannot be saved to the database, I'd opt for one of the two `guard` approaches, and which I picked would depend on how descriptive I wanted the message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own isEmpty function which takes an optional String and returns true if the string is nil or empty. Then to check many at once, you could make an array of the strings you were trying to check and filter it for empties.

```
let arr = [name, total, price, quantity]

let isEmpty = { (string: String?) -> Bool in
    guard let string = string where !string.isEmpty else { return true }
    return false
}

// if none of the strings are empty
if arr.filter(isEmpty).isEmpty {
    // do stuff
}
```

You could also make your own `any` function as an extension on `Array` or `SequenceType` that could be better than filtering.

Comment: There are simpler approaches than this, but the biggest problem here is that ultimately, we probably actually want to use the unwrapped values. Someone who takes your approach is probably force unwrapping all their values after checking with this approach.

Comment: That's fair, although you could use a similar approach that would unwrap the optionals. The original question was just checking for isEmpty.

Answer (score -1):

```
required_params = array('name','price',..)//all the keys required.
input_params = array('name'=>'abc', 'price'=>20,...)//input array in which conditions are to be checked.
foreach(required_params as $key_required){
  if(input_params[$key_required] is empty?)
    return false;
// if you dont have input_params array and have variables. just check
//${$key_required} is empty
  .....
}
```